# How to Convert Datetime value from lookup activity output to only a Date value into Set variable activity using AzureDataFactory

Tags: azure-data-factory

Can you please help me in formatting the Lookupactivity Output value from Datetime to Date type and pass into set_variable activity.

Step 1:
I am using a query in Lookup activity as SELECT CAST(MAX([DWHModifiedDate]) AS DATE) AS DWHModifiedDate FROM [Schema].[TableName]

The output from lookup activity is like  "DWHModifiedDate": "2022-11-18T00:00:00Z"

Step 2: Now i added a Set_variable activity and i want to store only the date from Lookup activity output for example the variable value should be only "2022-11-18".

Can you please help how to achieve this.

Comment: OK I think i got it with below expression 
@formatDateTime(activity('lkpactivity').output.firstRow.DWHModifiedDate,'yyyy-MM-dd')

Answer (score 0):

You can also just try to extract the required date directly using `@split()` function. The following is a sample and the output of look up activity looks as shown below:

[image]

- You can split on `T` and extract the 0th index to get the required output as well (since the date is already in the format of `yyyy-MM-dd`).

```
@split(activity('Lookup1').output.firstRow.dt,'T')[0]
```

[image]

- This would give the required output like `yyyy-MM-dd` format.

[image]

- Using `formatDateTime` also gives desired output.

Answer (score -1):

@formatDateTime(activity('lookupactivity').output.firstRow.DWHModifiedDate,'yyyy-MM-dd')